# SSRS Reports Running Slow When Connected to Report Server

Tags: reporting-services, odbc, opensearch, reportbuilder, ssrs-2017

I have been seeing this issue for the past week or so and I am experiencing some very weird behavior on SSRS. I am developing SSRS reports that connect to OpenSearch using their ODBC driver. The driver is configured on my local machine. If I go into Report Builder and preview a report that  queries OpenSearch, the performance is great, maybe a few seconds total load time from the moment I hit the preview button. However, if I connect to the reports server from Report Builder like so:
[connected to ssrs report server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkNiV.png)
It then hoses my entire Report Builder application. The report either takes exponentially longer to generate, or it freezes Report Builder entirely. Keep in mind that the datasource is not changing. The only difference is whether I am connected to the server or not.

If I disconnect from the report server by pressing the 'Disconnect' button in the above picture, the report then generates in 3 seconds-ish again. I am seeing the same kind of performance issues once the report is uploaded to the Report Server. The OpenSearch ODBC Driver configuration on the server is the same as it is on my local machine. Average load time is in the 50 second to 1 minute mark when it does complete. I say "when it does complete" because sometimes it also times out. Overall just super wishy washy performance. I've boiled the reports down to very very simple queries, basic "SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE .." so I do not think that is the issue. The reports also are not doing any complex grouping or sorting. I am also going the route of using query parameters and NOT using dataset filters.

At this point, I want to chalk it up to being an issue with the machine hosting the SQL Report Server. But I thought I would see if anyone else had similar issues.

Microsoft Report Builder: v15.0.19914.0

Comment: I have no experience of OpenSearch but I suppose I would first check if there are differences between your local pc and the server and their route to the OpenSearch datastore. Assuming they are different machines then try doing a trace route (`tracert`) from your laptop to the OS box and then from SSRS Server to  the OS box. After that just basic stuff like memory utilisation, odbc driver versions (and 32/64 bit versions) etc. Any other query tools you can query OS from to help narrow it down to/or exclude SSRS/report builder.

Comment: @AlanSchofield thanks for the tip, I can pull up dev tools in Chrome when clicking on the report from the SSRS GUI and it seems to hang on the call to the ReportServer path: /ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2FDEV%2FTestReport&rc:showbackbutton=true. It just sits in a status of '(pending)'

Comment: Sorry, I meant, do you have anything else you can use to get the data via the same ODBC driver (maybe a simple excel query for example) to see if the same thing happens there. Good luck!

Comment: @AlanSchofield Thanks for the replies. I tried this and Excel was able to pull back data right away. If you're curious, we have a nonprod OpenSearch instance using a different set of security measures in AWS. I hooked ReportServer up to this and the reports are loading just as fast as they do locally. The instance giving me the problem having a different mechanism has to be the next P.O.I. for me. I appreciate the feedback and second set of eyes.

Comment: Good luck, sounds like it could possibly be a routing issue. We had a similar things years back but in that case, accessing a remote server was faster than accessing the one in the same physical office. IT had messed up some routing and it was routing traffic out of the office, via headoffice back to our local office via a VPN and back to the server!!